# split the numbers and add them together code is not working properly, What is it am doing wrong?

Tags: java

I wrote the below code to split the numbers and add them together, it is working fine if my number is not starting with 1 eg, 123456 -- not working, 234567 -- working, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

```
public class Basic {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input = sc.nextInt();
    int sum =0;
    for (int i = 0; i <input; i++) {
        int A = input%10;
        System.out.println("test1 " +A);
        input = input/10;
        System.out.println("test " +input);
        sum = sum + A;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
    
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i <input; i++) {
```

You are dividing the int input into its digits. So the loop should run until all digits are eaten up:

```
while (input > 0) {
```

That should fix it

Answer (score 0):

In every iteration, you're updating `input`, so for example, step by step:

```
input = 123
i = 0
sum = 0

input = 12
i = 1
sum = 3

input = 1
i = 2
sum = 5
```

Then check the condition `i < input` it's `2 < 1`, it's not, so it's skipping the last digit, the same happens for `234` it returns `7` rather than `9`, because of the same thing.

You could change your `for-loop` for a `do-while`:

```
do {
    //Your code here
} while (input > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `i < input; i++` in your loop. It's not problem with only numbers starting with 1, for example `23445352` isn't work correctly too. I see `26` instead of `28`.

Check the next steps in the loop, for `123` input, after two steps, you have `sum = 5`, `input = 1` and... `i = 2`. So the condition for exiting the loop returns true without considering the last digit.